# Is it possible to intercept an outgoing SMS message on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sms

I am interested in writing an app that will intercept an outgoing SMS message and process it in some way before it is sent. Is that possible in the .NET compact framework? I have seen documentation to intercept and incoming SMS but not outging. If it is not possible in .NET, is there some other way that It can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no direct API from any .NETCF language to 'intercept' outgoing messages.

In C++ there are some possibilities; but I can't help you with that;
[Here's a thread on the MSDN forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/d19119ae-087e-4e34-b071-46cb7aa0acf5/)
It seems like you need IMAPISession.Advise to achieve this.